# Abort AJAX request via CancellationToken in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library, asp.net-ajax, cancellation

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that interacts with external resources and there is an operation which takes a lot of time.
So in controller I have method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SomeMethod(..., CancellationToken token)
{
    await _someService.ExecuteSlowOperationAsync(..., token);
    ...
}
```

And this slow operation looks like

```
public async Task ExecuteSlowOperationAsync(..., CancellationToken token)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
       //interacting with external resource
    }, token);
}
```

This method linked with modal view and if request will take so much time user might decide to close it. According to that I have to cancel request without awaiting results, so on client-side I have code like

```
...
var request = $.ajax(...);

...

$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  request.abort();
});
```

If I understood this [article](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx) correctly, cancellation token binds with request via framework model binder and no need to do something with it. When user close modal form, in browser concole I can see that request gets status "canceled" but on server-side slow operation is still executing. Aslo I tried with

```
CancellationToken disconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;            
var source = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, disconnectedToken);
```

and then took token from this source, but still got nothing.

I feel like I'm missing some important thing and have misunderstanding of this situation. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I am probably a little late with my answer. But I think I found your problem. Using `Task.Run(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` to cancel your long running operation might not always work.

[Using CancellationToken for timeout in Task.Run does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637642/using-cancellationtoken-for-timeout-in-task-run-does-not-work)

If the long running operation is in your own code, you should write something like this

```
public async Task ExecuteSlowOperationAsync(..., CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

If you cannot modify the source code of the long running operation itself, you can use `WithCancellation` from [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.threadingtools.withcancellation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Threading_ThreadingTools_WithCancellation__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396646/9483821 for more info) which you even could use earlier at your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SomeMethod(..., CancellationToken token)
{
     CancellationToken disconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;            
     var linkedToken = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, disconnectedToken).Token;
     await _someService.ExecuteSlowOperationAsync(...).WithCancellation(linkedToken);
     ...
}
```